# Getting random numbers from non-monadic functions

Tags: haskell, random, monads, type-signature

So my goal is to be able to call a non-monadic function and have it return a random value.

```
getNums :: [Int] -- this only works when the type signature is "IO [Int]"
getNums = getListFromIO 10

getListFromIO :: Int -> IO [Int]
getListFromIO n = do
  gen <- newStdGen
  return $ generateList n gen

generateList :: Int -> StdGen -> [Int]
generateList n gen = take n $ randomRs (1,9) $ gen
```

If I call `getListFromIO`, all is well; I get my precious random list of integers, and it is different every time. But every function that calls it must use `IO [Int]` it the type signature.  I don't want that.

How can I structure this so that I am able to get a random number list of type `[Int]`?

Comment: You can't. The whole point of the `IO` type is to prevent you from being able to do this. If you *could*, it would break your programs. You should instead ask how to use `getNums :: IO [Int]` in a way that lets you work with the `[Int]` value it computes in your other functions. This is what the `Monad` and `Functor` typeclass methods are for.

Comment: If you are feeling adventurous, you can use [`unsafePerformIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.0.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html). Note the **unsafe** bit.

Comment: Please don't recommend `unsafePerformIO` to someone who doesn't understand the dangerous ramifications of its use or the idiomatic way of writing Haskell without it. It is harmful.

Comment: That's why it's not an answer. I'm not recommending it, I'm making OP aware of its existence. Sweeping dust under the rug never helped anyone — this function exists and is a part of the standard library.

Comment: I'd much rather learn to do it the right way

Comment: @fjarri This is akin to saying "You can also point your gun at your foot and pull the trigger." Asking you not to suggest this is not "sweeping dust under the rug". It is harmful to suggest it and helpful to not do so.

Comment: Once again, it's not an advice, it's a bit of relevant information that can be of interest and provide some educational value (if he encounters some problems while using it). I very much doubt that OP is writing production code, so your analogy with the gun is not applicable here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, shouldn't, and don't need to do this.

You claim that all functions which use `getNums :: IO [Int]` must have `IO` in their type. This is simply not true. You can work with the `[Int]` value that the `IO [Int]` action computes in a number of ways, for example:

```
main = do
  ints <- getNums -- ints is now of type [Int]
  return (map (+1) ints) -- map (+1) does not have IO in its type.
```

This is one of the reasons that the `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad` typeclasses were introduced: to provide a consistent way to work with things like `IO [Int]` when you want to avoid dealing with `IO` everywhere.

Comment: That helps.  I'm going to have to think about how to work this into my code, but I see where this is going now.

Comment: @MarkKaravan A simple way of looking at it: You don't get the data out of IO and send it to your functions. Your top level glue code uses monad combinators to push the pure functions *into* the IO monad to operate on the data where it lives. (Or write do blocks, which is syntactic sugar for doing that).

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of IO is exactly to not allow side effects in pure code. All nonpure code must run in the IO monad. Randomness is also based on state, or reading from an external resource (global state). So what you are attempting is impossible without hacks. And I would strongly urge you to not use any hacks. Such hacks completely bypass the safety offered by the type system; they should only be limited to localized, safe hacks, primarily when the type system isn't smart enogh and needs some convincing. But that's not the case here — making a pure function deliberately behave like a non-pure one is very much not a localized hack as any code that calls it will inherit the broken semantics with no way for keeping track of where purity ends and non-purity begins.

It's best if you redesign your code to not need to generate random numbers in pure code. Just pass the randomness in from a high level point in your code hierarchy that lives in IO.

Comment: Perhaps I should add context.  I'm making a CLI sudoku generator that puts out a random board.  Is it more Haskellian to 1) prompt the user for explicit random input, or 2) pass around `IO Type` throughout the code?

Comment: @MarkKaravan False dichotomy. It is more Haskellian to do neither of those things. See my answer for the alternative.

Comment: @Erik Allik: can you provide an example of passing in randomness in from a high level point in your code hierarchy that lives in IO?

Comment: I was typing on the phone... a bit too tedious a way to write code snippets on a saturday night. Rein already got ahead of me and did a perfect job.